# Twitter API v2 spaces lookup ID

Tags: api, twitter

I'm wondering how the ID looks like in spaces lookup.

When I searched it in here,
(https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/spaces/lookup/api-reference/get-spaces-id)

the ID(1DXxyRYNejbKM) is a different format from the User ID(2244994945). Is it kind of location information?
If so, how to get an ID for spaces lookup?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Spaces ID from the results from the Spaces Search endpoint, or from looking up spaces by user ID. The format is a unique identifier for an individual Space, it is not a snowflake ID like a Twitter Tweet or User ID.